# Find points that contained by set of retangle

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, geometry, computational-geometry

**Input:**

- A set of rectangles (overlapping rectangles too) and a set of point.
- Coordinates are `integer` type.
- Rectangle 's sides parallel to axis

**Output:**

All points inside any rectangles given

---

What is the *efficient* algorithm and data structure should I use ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [sweep line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm): Sort the points by X coordinate. Introduce events when rectangles enter or leave the sweep line (the X coordinates of their left and right border). The rectangles currently intersecting the sweepline are a set of intervals when projected onto the sweep line, so they can be maintained using an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) or [segment tree](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/3327) (the latter only after Y coordinate compression, but you can do that as a preprocessing step).

With that setup, for every point you just need to check whether it intersects one of the intervals maintained by your data structure.

Runtime: *O((n+m) log (n+m))*

Answer (score 2):

2d segment tree [(example here](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/classes/cs437/fall07/Lecture5.prn.pdf)) is effective data structure to check if points are inside of any rectangle

Comment: Best to make a data structure out of the rectangles since there are more points than rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

The best idea I can come up with would be to check for every point `(x,y)` whether it is contained in any rectangle `(l,t,w,h)`, yielding a runtime bound of `O(nm)` where `n` is the number of points and `m` is the number of rectangles.

Comment: My problem is that the set of point is much larger the set of rectangle and I am asking for *efficient* algorithm, not naive solution.